# How to add commit back after reverting?

Tags: git

Let's say that I was working in a public repo and made 2 commits. Afterwards other people make commits for a while and then the administrator of the repo decides that my code has a bug in it. He reverts the commits and then continues working.

Later down the line he tells me that he wants me to make a new pull request with those changes on top of the current master branch. How can I do that? I just need to take those two commits that I made before and add them on top of master.. rebase doesn't work though because they are part of the history already?

Comment: You're asking a lot here.  Do you mean "revert" as in "This commit reverts <SHA>" or "revert" as in "I didn't merge your branch in"?  Be specific since the advice will vary.

Comment: this commit reverts SHA

Comment: cherry picking seems to have worked

Comment: What exactly did you cherry pick?  You've **really** got to be clear as to what you're doing here since I'm still completely in the dark as to what you're doing and why.

Answer (score 1):

Given a commit A which got reverted later by commit B, you can either cherry-pick commit A or revert commit B. Both should work fine and should give you your changes back.

Comment: Thanks yeah this worked. I guess people were confused by the question, but stack overflow people drive me nuts, seriously chill out. Don't talk to me like I'm a computer or I'll knock your lights out.